# How to design a structure of UIView Controller for dynamic contains

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, tableview, scrollview

How to design a screen structure with light weight loading and easy to scroll ??? 
Here is my current design structure. [image]

i am using table structure for set dynamic data. for main table as well as sub table. it working fine but when i am scroll the table it is not smoothly scrolling.

is there any other way to set this type of dynamic data ?? 
(Note: in Main Table no. of cell is dynamic not fixed , as well as each sub table also have variable no of cell not fixed)

Comment: Your issue is maybe in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Would you mind share it?

Comment: what is the reason for using this much tableViews? why not create one tableView with a couple of sections in it?